# Remove donate button on monitoring page of JavaMelody

Tags: java-melody

I have integrated JavaMelody for monitoring purposes, but after intergration on monitoring page "DONATE" button is being shown which is not suitable for client. now i want to remove. can any body help me Remove donate button on monitoring page of JavaMelody?

Answer (score 1):

JavaMelody is opensource and you don't have paid for it before selling its features to your client.

So I would say that removing the "Donate" button is not ethical.

You and your client should consider to click on the "Donate" button instead of removing it.

Comment: Perhaps there's a middle way - is it possible to pay JavaMelody project for a commercial license that would not have the "Donate" button?